# Borders does not work for ball in the JS game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple game that consist of pulling the ball by mouse clicking. So all work fine without one important think - the ball does not want to see the borders - `clientWidth/Height` coords of the playfield `field`.

I'm create a full-box conditions for ball borders, but somethink I may be missed. Can somebody explain me - what is the wrong?

```js
   var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
   var field = document.getElementById('field');

function getClick() {

    var fieldCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();

   var fieldBorderLeft = fieldCoords.left + field.clientLeft;
   var fieldBorderTop = fieldCoords.top + field.clientTop;

   var ballBorderLeft = event.clientX - fieldBorderLeft - ball.clientWidth/2 + 'px';
   var ballBorderTop = event.clientY - fieldBorderTop - ball.clientHeight/2 + 'px';

   if (ballBorderLeft < 0) ballBorderLeft = 0;
   if (ballBorderTop < 0) ballBorderLeft = 0;
   if (ballBorderLeft + ball.clientWidth > field.clientWidth) { 
    ballBorderLeft = field.clientWidth - ball.clientWidth;
   }
   if (ballBorderTop + ball.clientHeight > field.clientHeight) { 
    ballBorderTop = field.clientHeight - ball.clientHeight;
   }

   ball.style.top = ballBorderTop;
   ball.style.left = ballBorderLeft;
}

   field.addEventListener( 'click', getClick );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
 #field {
     width: 200px;
     height: 150px;
     border: 10px groove black;
     background-color: #00FF00;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 #ball {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="field">
    <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball" style="left: 140px; top: 39px;"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  </div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add the 'px' when you're assigning them as the new position.
You are adding them in the middle of your calculation. Which messes up the comparison. ie:
`ballBorderLeft < 0` becomes `'-10px' < 0` instead of `-10 < 0`
comparing the strings to the number value.

```js
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var field = document.getElementById('field');

function getClick() {

  var fieldCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();

  var fieldBorderLeft = fieldCoords.left + field.clientLeft;
  var fieldBorderTop = fieldCoords.top + field.clientTop;

  var ballBorderLeft = event.clientX - fieldBorderLeft - ball.clientWidth / 2;
  var ballBorderTop = event.clientY - fieldBorderTop - ball.clientHeight / 2;
  if (ballBorderLeft < 0) ballBorderLeft = 0;
  if (ballBorderTop < 0) ballBorderTop = 0;
  if (ballBorderLeft + ball.clientWidth > field.clientWidth) {
    ballBorderLeft = field.clientWidth - ball.clientWidth;
  }
  if (ballBorderTop + ball.clientHeight > field.clientHeight) {
    ballBorderTop = field.clientHeight - ball.clientHeight;
  }

  ball.style.top = ballBorderTop + 'px';
  ball.style.left = ballBorderLeft + 'px';

}

field.addEventListener('click', getClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #field {
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 10px groove black;
      background-color: #00FF00;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: pointer;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    #ball {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s;
      -moz-transition: all 1s;
      -o-transition: all 1s;
      -ms-transition: all 1s;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-drag: none;
      -ms-user-drag: none;
      -moz-user-drag: none;
      user-drag: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="field">
    <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball" style="left: 140px; top: 39px;"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As a side note, `if (ballBorderTop < 0) ballBorderLeft = 0;` should probably be setting `ballBorderTop`
And while you're at it, add `user-select: none;` on the `#field` css rule, to disable the text-selection.
Idem for the `user-drag: none;` rules on the `#ball`

Comment: Oh, yes... Thank you for your help! Now I understand! Cheers!